# select options with today's date as default?

Tags: date, selection, abap, sap-selection-screens

I'm trying to show todays date as the default value in a select date.

```
INITIALIZATION.
select-OPTIONS: so_date FOR sy-datlo.

START-OF-SELECTION.
so_date-sign = 'I'.
so_date-option = 'BT'.
so_date-low = sy-datum.
so_date-high = sy-datum.
APPEND so_date.
```

This isn't working though. Any ideas?

Comment: It wasn't showing the current date, just blank fields

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must set the value before START-OF_SELECTION:

```
select-OPTIONS: so_date FOR sy-datlo.

INITIALIZATION.
  so_date-sign = 'I'.
  so_date-option = 'EQ'.
  so_date-low = sy-datum.
  CLEAR so_date-high.
  APPEND so_date.
```

Did you try the easy version:

```
select-OPTIONS: so_date FOR sy-datlo default SY-DATUM.
```

I think it should work (can't test is actual).